# Server side video stream recording

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, kurento

I need to organize a short 5 second video stream from webcam, and record it on the server. The option of recording video on the client and sending it to the server with a post request does not suit me, because it's not safe and someone can spoof a video and send a fake. I need to record video directly on the server using WebRtc, because it's safe, but I have not found anywhere that will help me. I tried to use kurento media server, but it compresses with video codecs VP8 or H264, which spoils the quality of the video, and my neural network cannot process it. I need to save the video in original quality on the server. How can I do it? Or is there another way to transfer video to the server in its original quality, without the risk of getting a fake?

Comment: Recording WebRTC streams doesn't solve your spoofing problem.  I think you're far better off recording client-side where there is a priority on quality, rather than latency.

Comment: Yeah, but i need if for bank application, for transaction confirmation and identity verification. And security stuff is very important to me.

Comment: What's important to you doesn't change the laws of physics.  You cannot control what someone is sending you from the remote end, just like you cannot control who actually stands in front of an ATM and enters a PIN.

Answer (score 3):

Please note:

1. WebRTC uses VP8/VP9/H264 - so irrespective of media server, you will only get encoded video stream and not the raw YUV data. You may play with I420 codec though.
2. On Spoofing - WebRTC even allows streaming video content from a file - so technically speaking, WebRTC has no role in preventing spoofing.

Coming back to your key requirement - if you need to use original recorded quality video, you will have to capture frames from the camera yourself and send it to your server. You can refer WebRTC sample code in src/examples folder.

Another option (just a thought, I never tried) is to possibly add a dummy bypass codec in WebRTC but that's too complicated for your need.

Comment: No. WebRtc allows you to stream video from file throught webRtc dataChennel, not from mediaStream

Comment: You are misinformed. Please look at ./media/base/fakevideocapturer.cc But if you think you are correct, good luck with that. I have no more information to add.

Comment: ./media/base/fakevideocapturer.cc it's on github?